# ansible - read file, then randomly select entry

Tags: random, ansible

I'm using Ansible 2.9.10.  I am trying to read a file in which consists of a list of items. I then want to choose 3 random items from this list.  I've tried several things (noted below) but cannot seem to figure this out.
The file itemList is a list of items, one per line:

```
hammer
saw
wood
.....
```

In the playbook I have:

```yaml
vars:
  file_contents: "{{ lookup('file', 'itemList') }}"

# Printing file contents returns "widget\hammer\nsaw\nwood"..... etc. 
- name: Print file contents
  debug:
    msg: "File contents are {{ file_contents }}"

# Now try to select one random item from file_contents
- name: Select one random item
  debug:
    msg: "item is {{ item }}"
  with_random_choice: "{{ file_contents }}"
```

What am I missing?  It seems as though I am making it harder than it seems.  TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting the `file_contents` as 1 line, as below:

```
"msg": "File contents are hammer\nsaw\nwood\npencil\nfork\nspoon\nmobile"
```

this is 1 item and not a list of items (since the end of line character is not identified and is presented as a string sequence of '\n'.

one easy tweak is to split the 1 line string using the '\n' delimiter. Modifying your last task directly, you would use:

```
  # Now try to select one random item from file_contents
  - name: Select one random item
    debug:
      msg: "item is {{ item }}"
    with_random_choice: "{{ file_contents.split('\n') }}"
```

cheers